# Per App language android - android 13 . Context - getString

Tags: android, localization, android-context, android-13

val context = appContext

context.getString(key) is returning string in default language of system in android 12 , while it is returning string in selected language in android 13. Is there any alternative method to support for both. Needed string in the selected language

Answer (score 0):

It's a reported issue with Per App Language. This is the suggested workaround.
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/ContextCompat#getContextForLanguage(android.content.Context)

Use:

```
ContextCompat.getContextForLanguage(context).getString(R.string.myString)
```

instead of:

```
context.getString(R.string.myString)
```